# Error '$.type is not a function var obj = $.type( pref );' when submit a form in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

Recently, I'm using jqGrid to represent my business data set, and I find out there edit/add/delete/view functionality with jqGrid, so I try to use it. but I encountered a problem and I am not able to solve it after I try my best.

I do it following sample from this site:

```
jQuery("#deptGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#deptNav', {
    view : true
}, 
{
    jqModal : true,
    checkOnUpdate : true,
    savekey : [ true, 13 ],
    navkeys : [ true, 38, 40 ],
    checkOnSubmit : true,
    reloadAfterSubmit : false,
    closeOnEscape : true,
    bottominfo : "Fields marked with (*) are required"
}, {
    jqModal : true,
    checkOnUpdate : true,
    savekey : [ true, 13 ],
    navkeys : [ true, 38, 40 ],
    checkOnSubmit : true,
    reloadAfterSubmit : false,
    closeOnEscape : true,
    bottominfo : "Fields marked with (*) are required"
}, {
    reloadAfterSubmit : false,
    jqModal : false,
    closeOnEscape : true
}, {
    closeOnEscape : true
}, {
    navkeys : [ true, 38, 40 ],
    height : 250,
    jqModal : false,
    closeOnEscape : true
});
```

**UPDATE:** The following is all my including:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/styles/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/ui.all.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/themes/ui.multiselect.css" />

<!-- Including JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/superfish/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/tab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/thickbox/thickbox.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/thickbox/thickbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>admin/js/jquery/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>js/kevinshi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

UPDATE: Whenever I click button to edit/add/delete, it always causes error within firebug:

```
$.type is not a function 
var obj = $.type( pref );
```

I track that into the jqGrid source code, this error happens at line 52 of file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` as below:

```
stripPref : function (pref, id) {
var obj = $.type( pref ); // Happened at this line.
if( obj == "string" || obj =="number") {
pref = String(pref);
id = pref !== "" ? String(id).replace(String(pref), "") : id;
}
return id;
},
```

So, right at this minute, I can say that the `jQuery.type()` method is found, but I have included library `jquery.min.js`, I'm very confused.

Comment: Can you post the code where the type function should had been defined? This seems like its making use of a custom jQuery plugin but you had not explicity created it, thus making it undefined.

Comment: Just use this: <script src="<%=BASE_PATH %>jqGrid4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   just after jquery include

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to include two JavaScript files with implementation of the same module more as once. Moreover it's important to include JavaScript files in the correct order. Additionally you should not include any plugins which you don't use.

Typically one uses

```
i18n/grid.locale-en.js
jquery.jqGrid.src.js
```

during developing of some solution and uses

```
i18n/grid.locale-en.js
jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

in the final solution. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file).

One should include jQuery *before* any jqGrid JavaScript file. Including of `ui.jqgrid.css` and jQuery UI CSS is also required.

If you will have still an error you should post the exact line number of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` where the error occurred. You should post more full JavaScript code which you use.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. I follow your instructions to update the question. Please pay a attention at var obj = $.type( pref ); , which is at bottom of the question.

Comment: If functionality add/edit/delete cannot work on my development, I would give up on this solution and turn to others like developing them by myself. Thanks again @Oleg!

Comment: @BradyChu: We are now more close to the reason of the problem, but now one need to know the value and the type of `pref` in the case. Moreover it's good to know where `stripPref` was called. Moreover you don't included the definition of jqGrid which you use. It's especially important whether you changed the value of `idPrefix` option of jqGrid. The default value of the option is `""`. It should be no error in `$.type(pref)` with `pref` equal to `""` or any other string.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the exact same error message. I'm posting what worked for me in case it might help anyone else.
I was getting the **TypeError: b.type is not a function** when trying to save from a form.
The version of jqgrid I am using is 4.4.3, and I was calling an older version of jquery (1.4.2).
Using a newer version of jquery (1.7.2 in my case) fixed the problem. I guess the function 'type' was not in version 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. Just because of **`jqGrid`** doesn't support **`jQuery 1.9`**.