# JQuery jqGrid : first delete all child node then add one new childnode is not display

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am creating the nav links through `jqGrid`.
When I `delete` all `child node` dynamically and again I add new `child node` (dynamically) then that node is not displayed. (and not able to expand the`root node` also)

But if I do entire page refresh after deleting all `child node` and now I add new child node then I am able to expand that node.(by using expand the root node)

For deletion, I am using below code:

```
jQuery("#west-grid").jqGrid('delTreeNode', "NavID-favName1");
```

For add new child node, I am using below code:

```
jQuery("#west-grid").jqGrid('addChildNode', "NavID-favName2", "NavID-Fav", data);
```

and data is;

```
var data = {"id":"NavID-favName2","parent_id":"NavID-Fav","name":"favName2,
            "level":"1","parent":"NavID-Fav","isLeaf":"true","loaded":"true","expanded":"false",
            "url":reportUrl};
```

I am attaching the screen shot also.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6sA9.png  [Without Refresh]
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yljhy.png  [With Refresh]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

When I run in firefox with debug mode, While deleting, I found below javascript error;

TypeError: b.type is not a function at jquery.jqGrid.min.js (line 11, col 386)

Comment: Now Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the solution.

I was pointing to different version of jquery.min.js. 
Once I point to jquery-1.7.2.min.js, its working fine.

I got the solution from below link:

[Error '$.type is not a function var obj = $.type( pref );' when submit a form in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171900/error-type-is-not-a-function-var-obj-type-pref-when-submit-a-form-in)

When I run the application in Firefox debug mode then only I found the root cause of the problem.

Anyway thanks.